# ¿Cómo introducir una imagen base64 en un diccionario de Django/Python?

Tags: python, django, base64

Lo que yo hacía sobre el html es llamar a otro archivo html que contiene el img con su correspondiente cadena de base64 (para que no moleste semejante código dentro de un archivo trabajable):

```
#tienda1.html:
<img src="data:image/png;base64,...">

#index.html:
{% include "../assets/icons/tienda1.html" %}
```

De esta forma la imagen se visualiza sin problema. Mi consulta concretamente es ¿cómo puedo hacer lo mismo pero desde un diccionario de Django/Python?

Lo que intento hacer es algo como esto, sin embargo no funciona:

```
"productos":{
  "completo":{
    "destacado": "si",
    "imagen": "/template/assets/icons/tienda1.html"
  }
}
```

Esto compila sin problemas, pero el resultado es copiar tal cual la cadena de texto (normal, es lo que estoy haciendo):

```
<img src="/template/assets/icons/tienda1.html">
```

Lo que se me ocurre hacer es copiar el código de base64 directamente dentro de la clave del diccionario, esto en teoría funcionaría, pero como dije al principio, sería molesto tener semejante código dentro de un archivo trabajable.

El resultado esperado, como señalé al principio, sería algo como:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,...">
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo siguiente funciona:

- En `templates/assets/icons/` tienes un archivo llamado `tienda1.html` que contiene una línea como esta:

  ```
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,...">
  ```
- En tu JSON tienes, como parte del diccionario, una clave como esta:

  ```
  "productos":{
          "completo":{
              "destacado": "si",
              "imagen": "assets/icons/tienda1.html",
              "boton": "Continuar"
          },
    }
  ```
- En tu template tienes una línea como esta:

  ```
  {% for clave, producto in productos.items %}
     ...
     {% include producto.imagen %}
  {% endfor %}
  ```

Demo funcionando aqui --> https://repl.it/repls/SnivelingDapperKeygenerator

Nota: Lo suyo sería tener la imagen, ya codificada en base64, en la base de datos. O si no, tenerla como blob binario y pasarla a base64 desde el propio python, añadiéndola luego al diccionario del producto.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente! muchísimas gracias!!